# Null Reference Exception when Mapping a one column gridview to label controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, label

I have a one column gridview with data. I want to map the data on each row of the gridview to label controls. But I have an ArgumenyOutOfRange exception upon executing the code. Kindly view the code chunk below to understand my concept.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gvSurveyResult.DataSource = getStatusTable();
        gvSurveyResult.DataBind();
        gvSurveyResult.Visible = true;

        foreach (GridViewRow myRow in gvSurveyResult.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= gvSurveyResult.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Label lblResults = new Label();
                lblResults = ((Label)ResultsPanel.FindControl("lblResult" + i +".Text"));
                String gvCellText = myRow.Cells[i].Text;
                lblResults.Text = gvCellText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel the lblResults.Text is not getting the value passed to it by myRow.Cells[i].Text

I need to get the results out of the One column gridview and then map them to labels on the page. Thanks Guys for been there.

Guzzyman.

Comment: are you sure that you have column numbers in  gvSurveyResult grid greater than or equal to total row count?

Comment: There're no column numbers. Just a one column GridView

Comment: Well which is it?  A NullReferenceException or an ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Comment: @Moo-Juice NullReferenceException it is. Thanks for the correction. Would appreciate your response. Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write you code on row data bound event.

[GridView.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

That should be as follows

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Label lblResults = new Label();
        //lblResults = ((Label)ResultsPanel.FindControl("lblResult" + i +".Text"));
        //String gvCellText = myRow.Cells[i].Text;
        //lblResults.Text = gvCellText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @http://stackoverflow.com/users/853609/hkha what would be inside the if curly braces? i'm new to ASP.NEt as a whole and this is my pet project. How would my code fit into the if(){} statements?

Answer (score 0):

Two things

1. indexes are zero based, so your for-loop is incorrect(note that `gvSurveyResult.Rows` only returns `Data`-rows, not the header)
2. you are accessing the cell with the index of the row, you probably want to use `Columns`

---

This should work instead (although it doesn't make much of a sense to me):

```
foreach (GridViewRow myRow in gvSurveyResult.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < gvSurveyResult.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        string labelID = string.Format("lblResult{0}", i);
        Label lblResults = ((Label)ResultsPanel.FindControl(labelID);
        String gvCellText = myRow.Cells[i].Text;
        lblResults.Text = gvCellText;
    }
}
```

But i would use the `RowDataBound` event anyway instead of this loop.

Comment: Hi, This didn't work as I still have the same issue. How do I use RowDataBound in this situation.